# How do I getElementByID in Vimperator?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, vimperator

I've searched quite a bit and can't find the answer to my question. How do I get `getElementById` to work in Vimperator?? Whenever I try, it tells me:

```
"document.getElementById(...) is null"
```

This is a sample of what I put in the command:

```
js document.getElementById("myDiv").style.color="blue";
```

Any help is very much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea what vimperator is, but are you running this code after the element is ready, like in the `window.onload` event? And is there actually an element with that `id`? When you get that message that it's `null`, that means the element couldn't be found, whether it's because the element hasn't been rendered or because it truly isn't in the DOM

Comment: Thanks for the response. Vimperator is a Firefox extension that allows for mouseless browsing, inspired by vim. It's great. I run the javascript in the "command mode" after the page has been loaded (the element is there). This may be an issue specific to vimperator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the `js` command scope is XUL Chrome scope. That is the global object `window` this a XUL Window. The html window object for seleted tab is `window.content.window`.

So try to change your code to

```
js window.content.window.document.getElementById("myDiv").style.color="blue";
```