# View elements using javascript codes in vimperator?

Tags: firefox, firebug, vimperator

I tried to use a command like this in **Vimperator**:

```
echo document.getElementsByTagName("p");
```

To view nodes whose tag name is `<p>` in vimperator. However, the result is like this:

[image]

I also tried the same command in Firebug. Following is the result:

[image]

While **Vimperator**'s result is empty, **Firebug**'s is not empty. Does anyone know why Vimperator echoes the Collection whose length is zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the related question: [How do I getElementByID in Vimperator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15995201/how-do-i-getelementbyid-in-vimperator).  The short answer is to use `echo window.content.window.document.getElementsByTagName("p")` instead.